# Shall I rename user uploaded files?

Tags: django

**Django==1.11.6**

There are file upload attacks. But modern Django seems well guarded against them.

Django security guide is here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/security/#user-uploaded-content

Concerning user uploaded files it is much shorter than other security guides.

In the Internet we can find this kind of advice:

> The application should not use the file name supplied by the user.
>   Instead, the uploaded file should be renamed according to a
>   predetermined convention.

Well, I think that renaming is a good idea.

Shall I rename user uploaded files or it is not dangerous in case of modern Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why you should (in some cases, need) to rename uploaded files. So it does not even matter whether Django has good measures against some attacks.

- You have to deal with duplicate file names
- File names can be veeery long
- File names can contain characters that are not supported by the backend's file system
- Special characters in file names can cause problems when you want to access the files using a URL
- File names can contain lower/uppercase characters which might lead to duplicates on filesystems that are case-insensitive